# How do I fill a JScrollPane with a basic table

Tags: java, swing

My plan is to create a "basic" table template that will fill the JScrollPane every time the player creates a new playlist.

Netbeans GUI editor creates the code like so: 
    private void initComponents() {

```
    playlistsScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    playlists = new javax.swing.JList();
    musicFileTableScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    NewPlaylistButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    DeleteSelectedPlaylistButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    playlists.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
        String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });
    playlistsScrollPane.setViewportView(playlists);

    jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
        }
    ));
    musicFileTableScrollPane.setViewportView(jTable1);
```

I have my template:
    public class BasicTableGUI extends JTable {

```
JTable table;
DefaultTableModel musicTableModel;

public BasicTableGUI() {

    String[] columns = {"Artist", "Title", "Album", "Track Number", "Length"};
    musicTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 15);
    table = new javax.swing.JTable();

    table.setModel(musicTableModel);

    if (table.isEnabled()) {
        System.out.println("yess");
    } else {
        System.out.println("nsssss");
    }

    table.setTransferHandler(new MusicTableHandler(musicTableModel));
    table.setDragEnabled(true);
    table.setDropMode(javax.swing.DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT_ROWS);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    table.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

and I attempt to call it from netbeans' GUI code like so:

```
...


 playlists.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
playlistsScrollPane.setViewportView(playlists);


musicFileTableScrollPane.setViewportView(newBasicGUI());
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Uncompilable source code Erroneous sym type: 
javax.swing.JScrollPane.setViewportView
```

What is the correct way to call this table "template", BasicGUI when I want to, and have I created the BasicGUI class correctly?

Comment: Let's start with the main problem. The code isn't compiled properly when you run it. Next, you are creating two JTables, which doesn't really help. Personally, I'd drop the use of the form editor as it's getting in your way and configure the table in a single step

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the two tables. That was just an error in my copy and paste.

Comment: I don't see the need to recreate the table each time the user changes the playlist, all you need to do is change the data in the table model

Comment: @MadProgrammer - I've questioned that too. I was thinking it would make the GUI seem more responsive to have different table instances(playlists) in memory rather than changing the model. To me, it seems that reloading the table with info would cause a hiccup or pause. Then again - this is my first swing/GUI project so, I'm not coming from a very informed perspective.

Comment: Look at it this way...you have to repaint the screen anyway.  The `JTable` has been optimised to paint (reasonably) quick and it would cause, generally, less havoc across the container hierarchy, then switching the physical tables out might.  Besides, unless were talking tens of thousands of rows, I doubt you'd notice the difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never sub class JTable. You should create a class that extends AbstractTableModel and implement the data call methods. Then instead of this:

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
    }
));
```

you would

```
jTable1.setModel(new MyBasicTableModel());
```

Your MyBasicTableModel class will then hold all the data that will be displayed in the table. You may need to add extra methods so your program will be able to update the the data as needed. You also have to notify listeners when you get data updates so the table will be updated visually.

You can find more information at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: I wouldn't say "never", but that you should have very good reasons for doing so, but in this case, a factory method could be used to configure and instance of JTable to the required state...just saying ;)

Comment: I suppose you should never say never. :)